# Move li/background image with window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background-image

How do I move background images with the window upon resize? I am using a sprite, but if it is too difficult to do it that way that I can change the background image to single images. I have my code below:

```
html:
<nav class="topNav">
     <ulstyle="list-style-type:none">
           <li id="daily_sale" style="display:inline"><a href="/DealOfTheDay.asp?deal=" class="deselect"></a></li>
           <li id="my_account" style="display:inline"><a href="/login.asp" class="deselect"></a></li>
           <li id="support" style="display:inline"><a href="/terms.asp" class="deselect"></a></li>
           <li id="shopping_cart" style="display:inline"><a href="/shoppingcart.asp?" class="deselect"></a></li>

</ulstyle="list-style-type:none"></nav>
```

I also included 2 images. The first one is what is happening at about 1200px. The second is what it looks like at 1000px. What I want to do is slide the 'account, support, shopping cart' images over so that the space between them does not change. The 'sale' image should not move. Do I need javascript or can I do this with CSS?

[image: menu at 1200 px]
[image: menu at 100px]

Comment: Can you provide CSS also? Can you add both into a jsFiddle or something?

Comment: It's not pretty. I included the media screen I am using. http://jsfiddle.net/MrBlonde/Uh5Uh/

Comment: I have two 24 in monitors, i can only notice a difference when i expand halfway across my second and shrink from there, so jfiddle might not be the best test enviornment for this.

Answer (score 2):

I think the key question is the size of `<a>` is zero. so you should add a div into the `<a>` tag.
please refer to my amendment. by the way, the you should add `ul li{float:left}` to let the li stand Horizontally

http://jsfiddle.net/Uh5Uh/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

```
#my_account, #support, #shopping_cart{
    position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: But will that continue to slide them as I resize my browser? essentially, i want to maintain that space between AS i resize. similar to how the top menu on http://kershaw.kaiusaltd.com/ is set up

Answer (score 0):

In your jsFiddle, I'm getting the entire image stretching horizontally as I change window width. This isn't so much to do with your spacing increasing, it's occurring because your items are all positioned absolutely (so each item's left edge will **always** be that distance away from each other) and the width of the item itself is widening as you change page width.

Which stops once the window width is less than 1335px.

In short: your media query is mucking with your icons. It's stretching the images (because you used % for background-size, it is sizing the background to the width of the item, which is also a %, so is also getting wider.)

http://jsfiddle.net/Uh5Uh/2/

```
#daily_sale a{
    background: url('http://phantomsupply.com/v/vspfiles/templates/223/images/homepage/daily sale button black site.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Basically, removing the background-size (so the image doesn't stretch) don't muck with  the min- and max-widths, exchange the `left` properties on those three items for a `right` property, set the distances, and it will be fine.

You just have to set a min-width on body so that the items now don't overlap each other (since they're still positioned absolutely.) Alternatively, achieve it with floats instead of absolutely positioned elements.